# Can't understand the definition of a Java statement

Tags: java, jls

I think I understand this part:
**"Some statements contain other statements as part of their structure; such other statements are substatements of the statement."**

Source: (second paragraph)
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html

Please correct me if I'm wrong: This refers to method calls, which contain multiple statements within. This also refers to actions such as performing some kind of operation like calculating or concatting a String while initializing.

What I'm having troubles understand is this:
**"We say that statement S immediately contains statement U if there is no statement T different from S and U such that S contains T and T contains U"**

I'm not gonna lie, they totally lost me here. I can't imagine this in my head, or write it out on paper. The wording has me totally confused.

Can someone please explain this is an easier to understand fashion?

Comment: Hmmm, where is this? Can't seem to find it in JLS 8, although it could be Preview failing me

Comment: Ah, found it. Second paragraph of Chapter 14, if anyone else is looking

Comment: I'm sorry. Posted the link in the question. Thanks for reminding me @user3580294

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have for example

```
if (Expression1)
  while (Expression2)
    Statement1
```

then the `IfThenStatement` immediately contains a `WhileStatement`. It also contains `Statement1`, but it *does not immediately* contain `Statement1`.

Referring to the symbols used in the JLS spec S is the `IfThenStatement` which contains the `WhileStatement` T, which in turn contains `Statement1` U. Therefore S *does not immediately* contain U.

Comment: +1. Excellent example, and gets the point across much more effectively than my rambling description.

Comment: Wow, thats so much easier to understand. Thank you so much :D

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is referring to "how close" statements are to each other.

I suppose you can imagine the statements as a tree. The "overall" statement is the root, while substatements are children. What **"S immediately contains U"** could be roughly understood to be is "S is the immediate parent of U" in the statement tree -- that is, there is a direct link from S to U, with no nodes in between.

So that's what that sentence is saying. **"There is no statement T different from S and U such that S contains T and T contains U"** --> "There is no node T different from S and U such that U's parent is T and T's parent is S"

If you know how ASTs work I suppose this could make more sense...

Also, about the first part:

The sentence **"Some statements contain other statements as part of their structure; such other statements are substatements of the statement"** doesn't exclusively refer to method calls; in fact, all three types of statements (expression, declaration, and control flow) may have substatements. You can have an expression while declaring (e.g. initialization). You can have declarations in control flow statements (e.g. `for` loops). And so on.

For example, the if-then statement is defined as such:

*IfThenStatement:*

`if` `(` *Expression* `)` *Statement*

In this case, you have a substatement of the if-then statement without a method call in sight.

However, you are right in that method calls are one of the places where you can have substatements, in addition to the other cases you mentioned.